# cannot connect to oracle database with SQLPLUS via service name

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, service-name

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database from SQLPLUS using service_name but I received the

> ORA-12154 error (ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

NOTE: when I am using the SQL Developer, everything works fine.

here it is my tnsnames.ora settings:

```
SAMPLEDB =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = sampledb)
    )
  )
```

This is the connection command I use:

```
sqlplus test/password@localhost:1521/sampledb
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: Is that the *exact* command you are using? Is the first word really `plsql`?

Comment: my mistake, indeed, the command I use is `sqlplus ...`

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious (the command to start SQL*Plus is, of course, `sqlplus`), you are missing a line in the definition of the `SAMPLEDB` connect identifier.

Insert between the first and the second line the following line (EXACTLY as written below):

```
  (DESCRIPTION =
```

You must have deleted it somehow.

```
SAMPLEDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = sampledb)
    )
  )
```

Comment: I added the missing line but I have the same error.